# Using an IF statement

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP so my efforts may seem bizarre but I wanted to try my own experiments before writing up this question. My current code helps show what I'm trying to do so I've left it as is even though it doesn't work:

```
 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'MLB');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo '<p>Error: could not connect to database.</p>';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT rank, team_name, record, average, move, hi, lo FROM Rankings WHERE week_id = 4";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th style='text-align:left'>Rank</th><th style='text-align:left'>Team</th><th>Record</th><th>Average</th><th>Move</th><th>HiLo</th></tr>";
    // output data in each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td style='text-align:left'>".$row["rank"]."</td><td style='text-align:left'>".$row["team_name"]."</td><td>".$row["record"]."</td><td>".$row["average"]."</td><td ".if($row > 0) {echo 'style="color:green;"';}.">".$row["move"]."</td><td>".$row["hi"]."/".$row["lo"]."</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I'm pulling data from a MySQL database through PHP and displaying the database in an HTML table.  That process works fine.  Now I want to begin to make formatting decisions based off of the values pulled.  In the 'move' column of my table, I'd like to change the color of the text depending on whether the move is a positive or negative number.  I've tried using an IF statement within my WHILE with no luck.  Any suggestions?  Am I even close?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share the `if` that you tried?

Comment: @Mureinik scroll to the right.

Comment: wow, that's a great job of hiding it `-)

Comment: @Mureinik sure!  It's a terrible one but:    "</td><td ".if($row > 0) {echo 'style="color:green;"';}.">"

Comment: `I wanted to try my own experiments before writing up this question` is how SO should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `if` outside the `echo` and assign it to a variable, then use the variable in the `echo`. I'd also use ternary operator for this. It also looks like you are comparing the full array, not the index you want to be comparing. Try:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $style = $row['move'] > 0 ? ' style="color:green;"' : '';
        $row['move'] = $row['move'] == 0 ? '-' : $row['move'];
        echo "<tr><td style='text-align:left'>".$row["rank"]."</td><td style='text-align:left'>".$row["team_name"]."</td><td>".$row["record"]."</td><td>".$row["average"]."</td><td{$style}>".$row["move"]."</td><td>".$row["hi"]."/".$row["lo"]."</td></tr>";
}
```

The `?:` is known as [`ternary operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) it is a shorthand conditional. You can read more here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#PHP.

Comment: Small typo on the `$style = ` line; you have a right paren that doesn't belong there.

Comment: Thanks, missed that one.

Comment: @chris85 this worked!!  thanks!  I've modified the ternary operator a bit to change the text to red if the data is a negative number.  works great!  only problem is is that if the number =0 it is also turned red: `$style = $row['move'] > 0 ? ' style="color:green;"' : ' style="color:red;"';`  This is the first time I've used ternary operators, is there a way to include a third condition?

Comment: You can't have a third condition. What should happen on `0`? You could use `if {}elseif{}else{`. If you want `0` to also be green you can use `>=`

Comment: There is an approach with ternary you could try but it is not recommended `It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:`

Comment: @chris85 in a perfect world?  the zero would be changed to a dash (-).  For now, I'd take the zero remaining in it's original format, black.

Comment: @chris85 the new rule works great!  I also switched the ternary operator to this if statement: `if ($row['move'] > 0) {$style=' style="color:green;"';} else if ($row['move'] < 0) {$style=' style="color:red;"';} else {$style=' style="color:black;"';};` and now 0 is changed to a black dash!  thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think this will work:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td style='text-align:left'>".$row["rank"]."</td><td style='text-align:left'>".$row["team_name"]."</td><td>".$row["record"]."</td><td>".$row["average"]."</td><td ".($row["move"] > 0 ? 'style="color:green;"' : '').">".$row["move"]."</td><td>".$row["hi"]."/".$row["lo"]."</td></tr>";
}
```

This expression:

```
($row["move"] > 0 ? 'style="color:green;"' : '')
```

returns `'style="color:green"'` if `$row["move"] > 0` and `''` otherwise. (It uses the "ternary operator.")

**EDIT**

Changed to `$row["move"]` above per @chris85's comment.

Comment: thanks smarx!  I'm no longer getting an error message, but now all text in my column is green even when negative...

Comment: Then perhaps `$row["move"]` is always greater than zero?

Comment: Maybe try `var_dump($row["move"])` for one of the rows you think should be negative to see what exactly is in there.

Comment: I appreciate the help!  looks like moving the ternary operator outside of the echo statement made everything work right

Comment: That can't possibly be true. :-) Look for another difference between the code that worked and the code that didn't.

Comment: okay, I'll circle back and try to figure it out.  I really appreciate all the help!  You've helped keep me sane! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of:

```
if($row > 0) {echo 'style="color:green;"';}
```

a shorter if statement:

```
$Color = ($row > 0 )? "green" : "red";
echo 'style="color:'.$Color.';"';
```

Comment: Note that this would sometimes turn the cell red.

Comment: It will turn red if it's les than 0

Comment: Right. I'm just pointing it out, particularly for the OP, since this isn't what they wanted.

Comment: @onno204 I see what you're doing here, but when I implement it into my own code the text still doesn't change color.